What is the benefit of tailoring `mke2fs` regarding inode count compared to leaving the default
I have found that manually setting the -N parameter of mke2fs -t ext4 according to guesses or looking at df -i output creates much less inodes for a given size of a file system. Filesystem creation also is a lot quicker when forcing a full creation right from the start with -Elazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=1 as parameters to mke2fs.
After doing some research, I've not found an satisfying answer to my question in the subject line:
What is the benefit of tailoring mke2fs -t ext4 regarding inode count compared to leaving the defaults — from a today's viewpoint (almost ubiquitous SSDs, modern kernel, modern CPUs, lots of RAM).

Can you clarify what you mean when you say "...from a today's point of view"?

I thought I did with the catchwords between the braces.
